# Python opencv cv2.VideoCapture freeze

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, libgphoto2

My code always freezes on me. I'm testing it on this code.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0') # frozen
ret, frame = cap.read()
print(ret, frame)
```

My configuration is

- raspberry pi
- Python 3.9.2
- Canon 600D

this command works normally

```
gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

There may be a bug in the Cannon 600D.

Comment: What is the question in the post?

Comment: why it freezes on `cv2.VideoCapture ('/dev/video0')`

Comment: This question should be asked on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com people over there will be of more help.

Comment: why would you use ffmpeg to *write into* a video capture device? and how is that Canon camera attached? and why should it even be able to act as a video device, and not just mass storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it needed to run

`sudo modprobe v4l2loopback`

and

```
gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

and gphoto2 run

Answer (score 0):

you should add loop for your code. If u dont do this u always get only 1 frame from camera.
Example:

```py
    import cv2
    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0') # frozen
    while true:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            continue
        print(ret, frame)
```